# Concatenate Label with static text and dynamic vales

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightninginput

I have a lightning input where I'd like to create a dynamic label. When I deploy this component I don't have any errors; however, the UI displays "Please enter the {item.fieldValue}" in the label. How can I concatenate static text with field values into a label?

Comment: Please add your current code. There should be a straightforward solution here provided that `item.fieldValue` is set when the label is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

you can use it your JS controller to do it.

```
fieldLabel = 'Please enter the ' + fieldValue;
```

Comment: please avoid posting 1 liners as answers. Instead, explain how this addresses the OP's question and "how" this code can be used.